# How to implement CTRL-A key combination in C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I want to implement some action when CTRL-A is pressed . How can I do this in C++ on Windows Platform . I am using VS 2005 .

Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Keyboard Accelerator table in your resources, and then make sure you call [TranslateAccelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646373(VS.85).aspx) in your message loop.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645526(VS.85).aspx) for full details.

If you're using a framework (eg. MFC) then it will have its own way of wrapping accelerators - you need to look them up in the documentation of the framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely don't need accelerator and above code has no sense at all.
Simply use HK. See MSDN and Google groups for basic code (Win32)